# Error: "The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object" when add a look up field to a list

Tags: sharepoint, csom

In the following code, I want to add a lookup field to a list. However it got the error: "The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object". However, I don't know where i get it wrong. Can anybody show me?

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("samplesite");
SecureString password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "abcdxyz".ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("abcd@xyz.com",password);            
FieldLookup emp = context.CastTo<FieldLookup>(context.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Employees").Fields.GetByTitle("First Name"));
context.Load(emp);
context.ExecuteQuery();
projs.Fields.AddDependentLookup("Leader", emp, "Employee");
emp.AllowMultipleValues = true;
projs.Fields.AddDependentLookup("Members", emp, "Employee");
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Ps: The console show the address of the error is at the row: "projs.Fields.AddDependentLookup("Leader", emp, "Employee");"

Answer (score 0):

Seems "projs" is a list objeyt, so I tested like this:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/"))
{

                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                FieldLookup emp = ctx.CastTo<FieldLookup>(ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList").Fields.GetByTitle("MyLookup"));
                ctx.Load(emp);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList").Fields.AddDependentLookup("MyID", emp, "ID");
                emp.AllowMultipleValues = true;
                ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList").Fields.AddDependentLookup("MyCreatedDate", emp, "Created");
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to load a clientobject using different ClientContext. So make sure that **projs** using the same ClientContext.